# 0 datanodes when copying file from local to hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My OS is Windows 10.

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft x86_64) installed on Windows 10.

When I copy the local file to hadoop, I am receiving an error as 0 datanodes available.

I am able to copy the file from hadoop to local folder. I can see the file in local  directory using the command $ ls -l

Also I am able to create directory or files in hadoop. But if restart the ubuntu terminal again, there is no such directory or files exist. It shows empty.

The steps I followed:

```
1. start-all.sh
2. jps
 (datanodes missing)
3. copy the local file to hadoop
ERROR as 0 datanodes available

4. copy files from hadoop to local directory successful
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I deleted the all the files under the datanode folder manually using the command $ rm -rvf /hdfs/datanode/*. And restarted the hadoop /start-all.sh. Now datanode is shown and everything works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you stop/restart the WSL2 terminal without running stop-dfs or stop-all, you run the risk of corrupting the namenode, and it needs to be reformatted using `hadoop namenode -format`, not `rm` the namenode directory.

After formatting, you can restart the datanodes and they should become healthy again.

Same logic applies in a production environment, which is why you should always have a standby namenode for failover

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer. I am new to linux & big data. So, I didn't know that I should run stop-all or stop-dfs when quiting. I will follow the stepa (running stop-dfs or stop-all) to avoid crashes. Thanks.